# exportar a formato ovf u ova Ovm manager 3.4.4 desde la cli

Tags: oracle

Estoy tratando de exportar una maquina virtual en formato ova u ovf desde oracle VM Manager 3.4.4 utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
ssh admin@localhost -p 10000 "exportVirtualAppliance REPOSITORIO name=myvm  \vms=0004fb000006000061d443224aee4fdf"
```

Pero este me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Command 'vms=0004fb000006000061d443224aee4fdf' is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

He podido solventar el problema de la sigiente forma:

1. Realice una instalación limpia del oracle VM 3.4.4 sobre un Servidor oracle linux 7 nuevo
2. Obtener el UUID del Pool en el oracle VM server ir a cd /etc/ova-agent/db y ejecute el comando ovs-agent-db dump_db server (Observar la opcion manager_uuid) por ejemplo “0004fb0000010000e48a2ccbc5ac498e”.
3. Monte el cdrom y continue con la instalacion, detengase al momento de ejecutar el instalador y coloque: ./runInstaller.sh --uuid 0004fb0000010000e48a2ccbc5ac498e
4. Luego descubra el POOl y las maquinas virtuales.